# Is there a generic version of ExecuteChromeCommand on RemoteWebDriver to allow me to take full page screenshots with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using RemoteWebDriver to take screenshots of webpages, I would like to be able to take a screenshot of the entire page and have seen many examples online such as [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vTvzNY) which works out the size of the rendered page, sets the browser window size appropriately and then takes the screenshot.

These commands all appear to be browser specific (the example above is calling ExecuteChromeCommand on a ChromeDriver instance), is there a way I can do this via RemoteWebDriver?

I am only using a Chrome instance on the other end of the RemoteWebDriver call but they are in separate docker containers so needs to be remote.

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the driver itelf then you can determine the page width and height then set the driver window size to match.  I have the following as an extension method for taking full size screenshots.

```
 public static string GetEntireScreenshot(this IWebDriver driver)
 {
        // Get the total size of the page
        var totalWidth = (int)(long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.body.offsetWidth"); //documentElement.scrollWidth");
        var totalHeight = (int)(long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return  document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight");
        // Make the window the same size
        driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(totalWidth, totalHeight);
        var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
        return screenshot.AsBase64EncodedString;
 }
```